# How to ignore time in Datatables DateTime Filter

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I am using the Datatables Date Range Filter (https://datatables.net/extensions/datetime/examples/integration/datatables.html) but I have ran into an issue. It seems that in cases where you select a start date that matches the date of a row in the table it would not be displayed even though it should show all rows with dates >= start date.

Here is my code: http://live.datatables.net/topuhayo/6/edit

I believe that the issue may be that the start time is a DateTime object which could be causing unexpected behaviour since I am only trying to filter based on date not time.

Does anyone know how I could zero out or ignore the time?

Comment: Can you use `.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)` for your data objects to set the date time to the beginning of the ISO day?

Comment: @BeerusDev tried that, realized there are even more issues than I thought. I think something to do with timezones is messing up the filter, when I debug my code I noticed that a lot of the dates both in the table and from the inputs for the filter are off by one day

Answer (score 0):

date.toLocaleDateString() will remove the time